# String Trimming with Certain keyword

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, trim

I have a string like below.

```
<br><br><br><br><br>  SomeHtmlString  <br><br><br><br><br>
```

I want to remove br tags like trim function preserving middle br tags in SomeHtmlString.
Is there any function to do this shortly?

e.g.

```
<br><br><br>test1<br><br>test2<br><br><br><br>
```

to

```
test1<br><br>test2
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite understand your question. Can you give an example of the string before and after you modify it, please?

Comment: <br><br>test<br>test2<br><br> after removing first and last br tags , i want the string test<br>test2. Shortly i want the SomeHtmlString in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using regular expressions. It matches only one 
 at a time and replaces that either at the beginning of end of the string.

```
NSMutableString *replaceMe = [[NSMutableString alloc ]
             initWithString:@"<br><br > <br >  test<br>test2<br><br>"];
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
           regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^ *<br *> *"
           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
           error:&error];
do {
    ;
} while ([regex replaceMatchesInString:replaceMe options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, replaceMe.length) withTemplate:@""] != 0);

regex = [NSRegularExpression 
           regularExpressionWithPattern:@" *<br *> *$"
           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
           error:&error];
do {
    ;
} while ([regex replaceMatchesInString:replaceMe options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, replaceMe.length) withTemplate:@""] != 0);

NSLog(@"string=%@", replaceMe);
```

and that does strip `"<br><br > <br >  test<br>test2<br><br>"` down to `test<br>test2`.
It's probably not the neatest solution but it is very easy to modify to match different expressions, with different whitespace, for example.

It's also possible to use the regular expressions to match several `<br>`s in one go:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^ *(<br *> *)+"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:replaceMe options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, replaceMe.length) withTemplate:@""];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@" *(<br *> *)+$"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:replaceMe options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, replaceMe.length) withTemplate:@""];
```

which avoids the looping but is a little harder to modify.

Comment: this is the last solution that i am seeking. I was thinking there must be short way to do this in ios library. But it seems there is no function like this. thanks. i will give it a try.

Comment: this code did what i want to do. I accept this as answer until a short way found. thanks @emrys57

Comment: Thanks very much for the tick! I don't think there is a shorter way if you want it reasonably general. But, good luck!

Comment: second solution also worked.i prefer second solution. thanks again @emrys57

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
NSString* htmlString= @"<br><br><br><br><br>  SomeHtmlString  <br><br><br><br><br>";
NSString* pureString= [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<br>" withString: @""];
```

So you'll have @"  SomeHtmlString  " in pureString.

Comment: thank you but this is not my answer. SomeHtmlString contains <br> actually. I dont want to remove this middle br tags by replacing with "".

Comment: You want @"<br> SomeHtmlString <br>" ?

Comment: I couldn't explain clearly. SomeHtmlString is real web page body. I didn't write a long html string for becoming more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to strip out the unwanted bits:

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@""];
```

Then you would use something like this to remake your string the way you want it:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<br>%@<br>", yourString];
```

You might also want to look at stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:

There are so many things you can do with NSString. Check out the Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

EDIT:

substringToIndex: could be your friend here. You can do this to find out if the first 4 characters of your string consist of the characters you want to remove:

```
NSString *subString = [yourString substringToIndex:4];
if ([subString isEqualToString:@"<br>"]) {
    yourString = [yourString substringFromIndex:4];
}
```

Then you are creating a new string without those 4 characters. You keep doing this until the first 4 character are not equal to the ones you want to remove.

You can do something similar at the end of your string using substringFromIndex. You will need to know the length of your original string to make sure none of your substrings go out of bounds.

Comment: thank you but [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@""] this code will remove br tags in SomeHtmlString as well. I don't want to do this. Is there another way?

Comment: So you just want to remove instances of <br> from the beginning and end of the string. Do you know how many instances of <br> will be present each time, or is it a variable amount?

Comment: No. i dont know. it changes.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show a workaround for that problem. You would have to go through this process once for each instance of <br> at the beginning of your string and once for each instance at the end. It should keep trimming until you have got rid of them all.

Comment: i think i would use your last solution at the end myself. But it sounds me hard-coded. So i wrote this question. thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative regular expression rendition:

```
NSString *input = @"<br><br><br><br><br><br>test<br>test2<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
__block NSString *output;

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:input
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                         NSRange matchRange = [result rangeAtIndex:2];

                         output = [input substringWithRange:matchRange];
                     }];

if (output)
    NSLog(@"Found: %@", output);
```